# Heroku rake migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This error occurs when I try to run rake command on heroku. I am using Rails 3.0.7

```
**D:\Product\agent360>** heroku rake --trace db:migrate VERSION=20110513084747

rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Final::Application:0x7fc0f63088b0>
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handli
ng'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the recent release of `rake 0.9.0`.
There are several workarounds, however I suggest you for now to downgrade to rake 0.8.7.

In your Gemfile add

```
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
```

then run

```
$ bundle update rake
```

and commit.